# How to design forms using swiftui with sections having radius

Tags: ios, forms, swiftui, radius

I wanted to design a form using swiftui which looks like this
https://66.media.tumblr.com/8674652bc73f2cf387e29f067c07adac/tumblr_inline_py9ypv0dxv1qjmlje_500.png

The form has no background in the image and the section has a radius a different background color.

I have tried setting background color of form but doesn't work.

Any idea on how to design the form using swiftui.

Comment: Could you share code? What do you mean with the sentence "The form has no background ... color."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the rounded corners of the list cells with the the gray background this is part of the inset grouped table view style that is currently not supported by SwiftUI - only UIKit at the moment. 
https://twitter.com/twostraws/status/1142838324123656192?lang=en

For now, you can use the grouped list style in SwiftUI to create the darker background, the cells just won't be rounded like in your example. See: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-grouped-list

```
List {
        Section(header: Text("Examples")) {
            Text("Row 1")
        }
}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

Answer (score 1):

Available for iOS/iPadOS 14 on Xcode 12. You can use Form instead of List to have this appearance.

```
struct FormView: View {
    let destination = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                Link(destination: destination) {
                    Label("Terms and Conditions", systemImage: "doc")
                }
                Link(destination: destination) {
                    Label("Policy", systemImage: "doc.plaintext")
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
                Link(destination: destination) {
                    Label("Change Password", systemImage: "lock")
                }
                Link(destination: destination) {
                    Label("Security", systemImage: "shield")
                }
                Link(destination: destination) {
                    Label("Privacy", systemImage: "doc")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```